# run multiple instance of tomcat 9 on a single system window 8.1

Tags: tomcat, server

I have to run multiple instance of tomcat server on a single system with window 8.1 OS.I searched the topic I got the solution to make 2 copies of tomcat and change the ports in the server.xml file I tried it but  it didn't work tomcat still continues to run only on port 8080.Any help?

Comment: What do you mean 'it didn't work out' exactly? The approach is correct, if you have 2 copies that run on different ports - there should be no problem...

Comment: Dont know it does not work if run it directly but when I used cmd commands its worked fine for me

Answer (score 0):

you have to change server port and also ajp port in server.xml file than n than it will work.